# What benefits does C++11 bring in comparison to C++03?

Tags: c++, c++11

I will start studying C++11 in a month and was wondering, what benefits does C++11 provide when compared to C++03?

Comment: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html read.

Comment: an even bigger and horribly complex standard. http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/cpp.htm (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: The question "how is C++11 better than C" makes no sense. It's comparing apples and bears.

Comment: I do not see how it makes no sense. Simply what benefits does c++11 bring that did not exist or were more complicated to achieve on the previous versions. This is similar to me asking what html5 brings that was not in previous versions. I guess next time I will make sure to have several years of knowledge before asking a basic question.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's the same as the question 'How is C++ better than C?' which seems a fair question since C++ is often referred to as "a better C." On the other hand I would argue that it makes no sense to ask how C++11 is better than C++, because C++11 _is_ C++. Instead one might ask how C++11 is better than C++03 or C++98.

Comment: What benefits does Java have over PHP? Haskell over JavaScript? They're just different languages, and each has their use. Neither is "better" than the other.

Comment: @bames53 - Thank you will improve question then. I did not know those names.

Comment: @CYREX comparison btw c++11 and it's previous ver c++03 is ok , but comparing C++11 with C is like comparing java with javascript

Comment: @bames53: On the contrary. The assertion that "C++ is a better C" is just an urban legend and utterly misleading. On the other hand, asking how C++11 is better than C++03 is a legitimate question, since one is a proper step up from the other.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis - Thanks will have that in mind.

Comment: @KerrekSB You may disagree that C++ can be used as a better C, but that doesn't make it "an urban legend." It's an assertion made seriously by many people, and as such it is perfectly reasonable for someone to ask what it means.

Comment: @KerrekSB - To add to barnes53's point, in ForEveR's link above, Stroustrup's first bullet on the goals of C++ is that it is "a better C"

Comment: Your question mentions C, but your title doesn't. Was that a typo?

Comment: I don't like the title. It gives the idea C++11 is a different language than C++.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Then if you would like to change it according to something more correct (Would be helpful to me also). Apart from this I get the feeling (Actually not only be) in stackoverflow that questions coming from people with less experience get criticized more than other ones, limiting new people that have particular questions to be made here. This is something people with knowledge should remember, that they/you also started in a point where you did not know everything. Judging the question to quickly does not help the OP. Comments that might guide the OP are more helpful.

Comment: @CYREX You may not have noticed, but I already did change it :) I just added the comment to explain my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to nail it down to two things, I'd say that "rvalue references and variadic templates" are the most profound improvement of C++11 over C++03. Both allow you to do things that really *should* have been possible all along, and add enormous expressive power to the language. Finally you can have a proper `unique_ptr` and containers with move semantics thanks to rvalue references, and direct construction rather than copy construction thanks to both constructions playing in harmony:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void construct(void * p, Args &&... args)
{
    ::new (p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Another huge improvement is the incorporation of a memory model into the language that allows for a standardized description of concurrent execution (multi-threading).

There are tons of smaller additions that make the language more expressive, though, and allow you to do things you simply couldn't do previously:

- brace-initialization allows you to initialize class member arrays and value-construct automatic objects.
- initializer lists allow you to initialize containers.
- a better concept of constant expressions.
- a better-specified memory layout for classes and unions, as well as fine-grained notions of "triviality" to allow optimizations as much as possible.
- lambda expressions and closures make algorithmic and functorial programming much easier and more viable.

Comment: I'd add that lambdas combined with the standard library functions that take function-pointers or functors is a huge improvement too. Also: `auto`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(args)...` instead of `(args...)`?

Comment: @FredOverflow: It should, thanks :-)

Comment: I distinctly remember making the exact same mistake when I was new to perfect forwarding :)

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ are completely different languages, so there's no point in answering that part of the question.

As for C++ to C++11, you're just getting more modern features added to the language that help you to write better object oriented code.

Libraries have been developed over time in BOOST and in other places that let you use:

- Smart Pointers
- Regex
- Lambda expressions
- Automatic variables
- etc.

So, for the most part, you have more libraries that support your coding so you can use more "standard" code and write less user code.  This means you're debugging lest and coding faster.

**Added Note:** Many of these features are around to promote good programming practice in general.  For example, smart pointers help you to use RAII (Resource Allocation is Initialization) to ensure your dynamically obtained resources are freed when they are no longer referred to.

Using C++11 is like getting the new Ferrari when you already own one.  The old one is good and gets the job done, but the new one is better and has sweet new features which let you drive the same courses safer and faster while having more fun along the way :)

Comment: So basically I can debug less and the code is more user friendly? or the learning curve is less steep.

Comment: Well, do you trust your own code more, or the code that tens of thousands of good developers have been debugging for years? :)  Also though, using standard code is faster and has less of a curve.  You can google how to do a regular expression in 5 minutes, writing the code to do what a complex regex does might take you days to debug.

Comment: Good points there W00te.

Answer (score 3):

The goal of C++11 was to improve on all the things C++ is good at; expressiveness, performance, type safety, and to improve things C++ isn't so great at; consistency and ease of learning. C++11 also adds support for trends in computing that became more important after C++98 was first standardized, such as multi-threading

For performance C++11 adds rvalue references which allow C++11 code to avoid some expensive copies without hard to read or understand workarounds sometimes used in C++03. And any new features still follow the maxim of "don't pay for what you don't use," maintaining C++'s capability for performance.

C++11 adds a lot for expressiveness, including variadic templates, generalized attributes, user defined literals, and defaulted special functions. C++11 also makes it much easier to express certain things that could be done with C++03 but less easily, such as static assertions, compile-time expressions, and template-able type aliases, and deleted special functions.

For type-safety there are now strongly typed enums, explicit conversion operators, initialization syntax that won't do conversions that lose precision, the nullptr keyword.

C++11 removes many restrictions to make it more consistent and easier to learn. Some examples are non-static data members' in-class initialization, inheriting/delegating constructors, initializer lists, the right-angle bracket fix, default template arguments for function templates, enum forward declarations, unrestricted unions, etc. Also many new features can each 'replace' several older features, meaning a new programmer needs to learn less to get started.

---

Originally the question also asked for a comparison to C.

With regards to C++ and C, C++11 brings many improvements that mirror features added to C since the original C++ standard (C++98) based off pre-C99 C. For example C++11 adds C99's variadic macros, `long long`, requirements on extended integral types, and the `__func__` predefined identifier. C++11 now mandates the layout for complex numbers, making it compatible with the (presumed) layout of _Complex numbers in C99. Other features can be used in place of features added to C, such as C++11's uniform initialization syntax in place of C99's compund literals.